# How to fill form with select option data?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I need to select option that contains form data in a json format to fill form with onChange event.
here is an html example:

```
<select>
     <option value='{"firstname":"test","lastname":"test","tel":"test"}'>Irakli</option>
</select>
<form>
     <input name="firstname"/>
     <input name="lastname"/>
     <input name="tel"/>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `useRef` hook to access DOM and update values like this:

```
import { useRef } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const firstnameRef = useRef();
  const lastnameRef = useRef();
  const telRef = useRef();

  const handleOnChange = (e) => {
    const currentValue = e.target.value;
    if (currentValue) {
      const currentObject = JSON.parse(currentValue);
      firstnameRef.current.value = currentObject.firstname;
      lastnameRef.current.value = currentObject.lastname;
      telRef.current.value = currentObject.tel;
    } else {
      firstnameRef.current.value = "";
      lastnameRef.current.value = "";
      telRef.current.value = "";
    }
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <select onChange={handleOnChange}>
        <option value="">please select</option>
        <option value='{"firstname":"test","lastname":"test","tel":"test"}'>
          Irakli
        </option>
        <option value='{"firstname":"name2","lastname":"lastname2","tel":"tel2"}'>
          Option2
        </option>
        <option value='{"firstname":"name3","lastname":"lastname3","tel":"tel3"}'>
          Option3
        </option>
      </select>
      <form>
        <input ref={firstnameRef} name="firstname" />
        <input ref={lastnameRef} name="lastname" />
        <input ref={telRef} name="tel" />
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}
```

You can take a look at [this sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/nostalgic-snow-cqi9mw?file=/src/App.js:0-1281) for a live working example of this solution.

Answer (score 0):

you can have an initial state as your json, and then with event handlers parsing the value you can set to form accordingly ...

sample e.g.

```js
// Get a hook function
const {useState} = React;

const App = () => {
    const [formVal, setFormVal] = useState({"firstname":"","lastname":"","tel":""});
  
    const handleSelectChange = (e) => {
       const {value} = e.target;
       const parsed = JSON.parse(value);
       setFormVal(parsed);
    }
    
    const handleInputChange = (e) => {
       const {value, name} = e.target;
       setFormVal(prev=> ({...prev, [name] : value}) )
    }
    
    return (
       <div>
        <select onChange={handleSelectChange}>
          <option value='{"firstname":"","lastname":"","tel":""}'>Select</option>
          <option value='{"firstname":"test","lastname":"test","tel":"test"}'>Irakli</option>
        </select>
        <br></br>
        <form>
             <label>First Name: <input value={formVal.firstname} onChange={handleInputChange} name="firstname"/></label><br></br>
             <label>Last Name: <input value={formVal.lastname} onChange={handleInputChange} name="lastname"/></label><br></br>
             <label>Tel: <input value={formVal.tel} onChange={handleInputChange} name="tel"/></label>
        </form>
       </div>  
    );
};

// Render it
ReactDOM.createRoot(
    document.getElementById("root")
).render(
    <App/>
);
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.1.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.1.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
```